# How to pinpoint the cause of a system crash?

Tags: windows-7, crash, bsod

I'm running Windows 7 SP1 64-bit. My system has been running great lately, but it crashed all of a sudden. I checked the system event logs and found this:

> The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was:
>   0x000000d1 (0x00001000000102fd, 0x0000000000000002,
>   0x0000000000000000, 0xfffff88010143afd). A dump was saved in:
>   C:\Windows\Minidump\052714-23010-01.dmp. Report Id: 052714-23010-01.

Here's a link to the file mentioned above:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ag19ejkrddnjjct/052714-23010-01.dmp

Can those cryptic codes be deciphered somehow? How can I determine what caused this BSOD?

Comment: I've reworded your question, which has been since closed. Consider editing it further to provide additional details, which are always welcome. Also, check this help article out: [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](http://superuser.com/help/reopen-questions)

Comment: Your post is closed and I can't answer, but the analysis by the suggested BlueScreenView utility doesn't agree with the existing answers. It seems as though the problem is caused by the driver cdrom.sys dating from 20/11/2010. My own cdrom.sys dates from 21/11/2010, so you are missing some Windows update. Try deleting the driver and rebooting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Analysis

Crash dumps can be analyzed using [WinDbg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg), which is part of the official [Microsoft debugging tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I'm going to highlight just the most significant data, providing the full command output for reference.

### Machine information

```
BiosVendor = Award Software International, Inc.
BiosVersion = F4a
BiosReleaseDate = 05/15/2011
SystemManufacturer = Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
SystemProductName = G1.Guerrilla
```

### Operating system

```
Windows 7 Kernel Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (8 procs) Free x64
```

### Bug check

The [bug check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatal_system_error) code is `0xD1`, which translates to `DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL`:

> A driver tried to access an address that is pageable (or that is completely invalid) while the IRQL was too high.
>
> This bug check is usually caused by drivers that have used improper addresses.
>
> <sub>Source: [Bug Check 0xD1: DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560244%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</sub>

#### Stack trace

Checking the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), the `Xeno7x64` module appears to be the cause:

```
STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`0ed445d8 fffff800`03492169 : 00000000`0000000a 00001000`000102fd 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`0ed445e0 fffff800`03490de0 : 00000000`00538968 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`12e1e270 00000000`00000067 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
fffff880`0ed44720 fffff880`10143afd : fffff880`0ed44998 fffff880`0ed44980 00000000`0000445c fffff880`10139fc6 : nt!KiPageFault+0x260
fffff880`0ed448b0 fffff880`0ed44998 : fffff880`0ed44980 00000000`0000445c fffff880`10139fc6 fffffa80`175954e8 : Xeno7x64+0x17afd
```

#### Faulting driver

The `Xeno7x64.sys` file is a 64-bit driver which is related to a network card device identified as **Bigfoot Killer Xeno Gaming PCI device**. Quoting Wikipedia:

> The **Killer NIC** ([Network Interface Card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Interface_Card)), from Killer Gaming, is designed to circumvent the [Microsoft Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) [TCP/IP stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite), and handle processing on the card via a dedicated [network processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_processor). Most standard [network cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_card) are host based, and make use of the primary [CPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit). The manufacturer claims that the Killer NIC is capable of reducing network [latency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latency_(engineering)) and [lag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lag).
>
> <sub>Source: [Killer NIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killer_NIC)</sub>

The driver was built on May 19, 2011:

```
fffff880`1012c000 fffff880`10155000   Xeno7x64  Thu May 19 00:55:16 2011 (4DD44E54)
```

#### Other details

The issue occurred after the system had been running for more than 13 hours:

```
System Uptime: 0 days 13:09:04.168
```

When the system crashed [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) was open:

```
PROCESS_NAME:  Dropbox.exe
```

### Additional information

Here's the output retrieved through WinDbg:

```
7: kd> !sysinfo machineid
Machine ID Information [From Smbios 2.4, DMIVersion 36, Size=1252]
BiosVendor = Award Software International, Inc.
BiosVersion = F4a
BiosReleaseDate = 05/15/2011
SystemManufacturer = Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
SystemProductName = G1.Guerrilla
SystemFamily =  
SystemVersion =  
SystemSKU =  
BaseBoardManufacturer = Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
BaseBoardProduct = G1.Guerrilla
BaseBoardVersion = x.x

7: kd> vertarget
Windows 7 Kernel Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 7601.18409.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.140303-2144
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`0341d000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`03660890
Debug session time: Wed May 28 05:27:22.232 2014 (UTC + 2:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 13:09:04.168

7: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (d1)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If kernel debugger is available get stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00001000000102fd, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
Arg4: fffff88010143afd, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------


READ_ADDRESS: GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from fffff800036ca100
GetUlongFromAddress: unable to read from fffff800036ca1c0
 00001000000102fd Nonpaged pool

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

FAULTING_IP: 
Xeno7x64+17afd
fffff880`10143afd 488b07          mov     rax,qword ptr [rdi]

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xD1

PROCESS_NAME:  Dropbox.exe

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.16384 (debuggers(dbg).130821-1623) x86fre

TRAP_FRAME:  fffff8800ed44720 -- (.trap 0xfffff8800ed44720)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=fffffa801741a332 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=fffffa801741a332
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff88010143afd rsp=fffff8800ed448b0 rbp=fffffa801756d1a0
 r8=fffff8800c97a560  r9=0000000000000000 r10=38203a22746e695f
r11=fffffa801741a332 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po cy
Xeno7x64+0x17afd:
fffff880`10143afd 488b07          mov     rax,qword ptr [rdi] ds:00000000`00000000=????????????????
Resetting default scope

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80003492169 to fffff80003492bc0

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`0ed445d8 fffff800`03492169 : 00000000`0000000a 00001000`000102fd 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`0ed445e0 fffff800`03490de0 : 00000000`00538968 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`12e1e270 00000000`00000067 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
fffff880`0ed44720 fffff880`10143afd : fffff880`0ed44998 fffff880`0ed44980 00000000`0000445c fffff880`10139fc6 : nt!KiPageFault+0x260
fffff880`0ed448b0 fffff880`0ed44998 : fffff880`0ed44980 00000000`0000445c fffff880`10139fc6 fffffa80`175954e8 : Xeno7x64+0x17afd
fffff880`0ed448b8 fffff880`0ed44980 : 00000000`0000445c fffff880`10139fc6 fffffa80`175954e8 00000000`00000001 : 0xfffff880`0ed44998
fffff880`0ed448c0 00000000`0000445c : fffff880`10139fc6 fffffa80`175954e8 00000000`00000001 fffffa80`1363ab00 : 0xfffff880`0ed44980
fffff880`0ed448c8 fffff880`10139fc6 : fffffa80`175954e8 00000000`00000001 fffffa80`1363ab00 fffffa80`1756d1a0 : 0x445c
fffff880`0ed448d0 fffffa80`175954e8 : 00000000`00000001 fffffa80`1363ab00 fffffa80`1756d1a0 fffffa80`16fb2180 : Xeno7x64+0xdfc6
fffff880`0ed448d8 00000000`00000001 : fffffa80`1363ab00 fffffa80`1756d1a0 fffffa80`16fb2180 fffffa80`18f20740 : 0xfffffa80`175954e8
fffff880`0ed448e0 fffffa80`1363ab00 : fffffa80`1756d1a0 fffffa80`16fb2180 fffffa80`18f20740 fffffa80`17630330 : 0x1
fffff880`0ed448e8 fffffa80`1756d1a0 : fffffa80`16fb2180 fffffa80`18f20740 fffffa80`17630330 fffffa80`16cc3b30 : 0xfffffa80`1363ab00
fffff880`0ed448f0 fffffa80`16fb2180 : fffffa80`18f20740 fffffa80`17630330 fffffa80`16cc3b30 fffff880`0c97a560 : 0xfffffa80`1756d1a0
fffff880`0ed448f8 fffffa80`18f20740 : fffffa80`17630330 fffffa80`16cc3b30 fffff880`0c97a560 fffff880`10143d65 : 0xfffffa80`16fb2180
fffff880`0ed44900 fffffa80`17630330 : fffffa80`16cc3b30 fffff880`0c97a560 fffff880`10143d65 fffffa80`1756d1a0 : 0xfffffa80`18f20740
fffff880`0ed44908 fffffa80`16cc3b30 : fffff880`0c97a560 fffff880`10143d65 fffffa80`1756d1a0 00000000`0000445c : 0xfffffa80`17630330
fffff880`0ed44910 fffff880`0c97a560 : fffff880`10143d65 fffffa80`1756d1a0 00000000`0000445c fffff880`0c97a560 : 0xfffffa80`16cc3b30
fffff880`0ed44918 fffff880`10143d65 : fffffa80`1756d1a0 00000000`0000445c fffff880`0c97a560 fffffa80`16fb2180 : 0xfffff880`0c97a560
fffff880`0ed44920 fffffa80`1756d1a0 : 00000000`0000445c fffff880`0c97a560 fffffa80`16fb2180 fffffa80`16cc3b30 : Xeno7x64+0x17d65
fffff880`0ed44928 00000000`0000445c : fffff880`0c97a560 fffffa80`16fb2180 fffffa80`16cc3b30 fffff880`10133326 : 0xfffffa80`1756d1a0
fffff880`0ed44930 fffff880`0c97a560 : fffffa80`16fb2180 fffffa80`16cc3b30 fffff880`10133326 00000000`00000000 : 0x445c
fffff880`0ed44938 fffffa80`16fb2180 : fffffa80`16cc3b30 fffff880`10133326 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`16fb2180 : 0xfffff880`0c97a560
fffff880`0ed44940 fffffa80`16cc3b30 : fffff880`10133326 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`16fb2180 fffffa80`16fb2180 : 0xfffffa80`16fb2180
fffff880`0ed44948 fffff880`10133326 : 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`16fb2180 fffffa80`16fb2180 fffffa80`1756d1a0 : 0xfffffa80`16cc3b30
fffff880`0ed44950 00000000`00000000 : fffffa80`16fb2180 fffffa80`16fb2180 fffffa80`1756d1a0 fffff880`0c97a560 : Xeno7x64+0x7326


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
Xeno7x64+17afd
fffff880`10143afd 488b07          mov     rax,qword ptr [rdi]

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

SYMBOL_NAME:  Xeno7x64+17afd

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: Xeno7x64

IMAGE_NAME:  Xeno7x64.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4dd44e54

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xD1_Xeno7x64+17afd

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xD1_Xeno7x64+17afd

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0xd1_xeno7x64+17afd

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {7f7f4b8b-1c65-834f-52ad-a3a52f1fc51e}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

7: kd> lmsmt
start             end                 module name
fffff880`00e00000 fffff880`00e57000   ACPI      Sat Nov 20 10:19:16 2010 (4CE79294)
fffff880`04836000 fffff880`048bf000   afd       Sat Sep 28 03:09:07 2013 (52462C33)
fffff880`10198000 fffff880`101ae000   AgileVpn  Tue Jul 14 02:10:24 2009 (4A5BCCF0)
fffff880`01520000 fffff880`0152b000   amdxata   Fri Mar 19 17:18:18 2010 (4BA3A3CA)
fffff880`09bef000 fffff880`09bfa000   asyncmac  Tue Jul 14 02:10:13 2009 (4A5BCCE5)
fffff880`01390000 fffff880`01399000   atapi     Tue Jul 14 01:19:47 2009 (4A5BC113)
fffff880`01399000 fffff880`013c3000   ataport   Mon Aug 05 03:02:45 2013 (51FEF9B5)
fffff960`008f0000 fffff960`00951000   ATMFD     Thu Jun 06 05:30:53 2013 (51B0026D)
fffff880`05753000 fffff880`0577c000   avgdiska  Tue May 13 14:05:03 2014 (53720A6F)
fffff880`05713000 fffff880`05753000   avgidsdrivera  Tue May 13 14:04:50 2014 (53720A62)
fffff880`01000000 fffff880`01031000   avgidsha  Tue May 13 14:05:36 2014 (53720A90)
fffff880`056d5000 fffff880`05713000   avgldx64  Tue May 13 14:20:22 2014 (53720E06)
fffff880`00faf000 fffff880`01000000   avgloga   Tue May 13 14:06:01 2014 (53720AA9)
fffff880`017d4000 fffff880`017f7000   avgmfx64  Tue May 13 14:05:03 2014 (53720A6F)
fffff880`01bef000 fffff880`01bf9000   avgrkx64  Tue May 13 14:04:26 2014 (53720A4A)
fffff880`04676000 fffff880`046bc000   avgtdia   Tue May 13 14:20:00 2014 (53720DF0)
fffff880`047b2000 fffff880`047c2000   avgtpx64  Thu Mar 20 17:30:04 2014 (532B178C)
fffff880`047ab000 fffff880`047b2000   Beep      Tue Jul 14 02:00:13 2009 (4A5BCA8D)
fffff880`056c4000 fffff880`056d5000   blbdrive  Tue Jul 14 01:35:59 2009 (4A5BC4DF)
fffff880`09b81000 fffff880`09b9f000   bowser    Wed Feb 23 05:55:04 2011 (4D649328)
fffff960`00750000 fffff960`00777000   cdd       Thu Feb 03 12:25:25 2011 (4D4A90A5)
fffff880`08791000 fffff880`087ae000   cdfs      Tue Jul 14 01:19:46 2009 (4A5BC112)
fffff880`04778000 fffff880`047a2000   cdrom     Sat Nov 20 10:19:20 2010 (4CE79298)
fffff880`00d1a000 fffff880`00dda000   CI        Sat Nov 20 14:12:36 2010 (4CE7C944)
fffff880`01200000 fffff880`01230000   CLASSPNP  Sat Nov 20 10:19:23 2010 (4CE7929B)
fffff880`00cbc000 fffff880`00d1a000   CLFS      Tue Jul 14 01:19:57 2009 (4A5BC11D)
fffff880`01891000 fffff880`01903000   cng       Wed Aug 01 17:48:07 2012 (50194FB7)
fffff880`06a00000 fffff880`06a10000   CompositeBus  Sat Nov 20 11:33:17 2010 (4CE7A3ED)
fffff880`08ec3000 fffff880`08ed1000   crashdmp  Tue Jul 14 02:01:01 2009 (4A5BCABD)
fffff880`05623000 fffff880`056a6000   csc       Sat Nov 20 10:27:12 2010 (4CE79470)
fffff880`056a6000 fffff880`056c4000   dfsc      Sat Nov 20 10:26:31 2010 (4CE79447)
fffff880`0499f000 fffff880`049ae000   discache  Tue Jul 14 01:37:18 2009 (4A5BC52E)
fffff880`01800000 fffff880`01816000   disk      Tue Jul 14 01:19:57 2009 (4A5BC11D)
fffff880`06d55000 fffff880`06d77000   drmk      Fri Oct 04 04:16:30 2013 (524E24FE)
fffff880`08f6a000 fffff880`08f7d000   dump_dumpfve  Tue Jul 14 01:21:51 2009 (4A5BC18F)
fffff880`08edb000 fffff880`08f6a000   dump_mvs91xx  Tue Aug 09 05:05:23 2011 (4E40A3F3)
fffff880`0475d000 fffff880`04765000   dump_mvxxmm  Tue Aug 09 05:05:06 2011 (4E40A3E2)
fffff880`08ed1000 fffff880`08edb000   dump_storport  Tue Feb 04 02:36:25 2014 (52F04419)
fffff880`08e9c000 fffff880`08ea8000   Dxapi     Tue Jul 14 01:38:28 2009 (4A5BC574)
fffff880`06a24000 fffff880`06b18000   dxgkrnl   Thu Aug 01 09:58:53 2013 (51FA153D)
fffff880`06b18000 fffff880`06b5e000   dxgmms1   Wed Apr 10 05:27:15 2013 (5164DC13)
fffff880`06cc4000 fffff880`06ccf000   Edge7x64  Thu May 19 00:55:15 2011 (4DD44E53)
fffff880`01577000 fffff880`0158b000   fileinfo  Tue Jul 14 01:34:25 2009 (4A5BC481)
fffff880`0152b000 fffff880`01577000   fltmgr    Sat Nov 20 10:19:24 2010 (4CE7929C)
fffff880`01914000 fffff880`0191e000   Fs_Rec    Thu Mar 01 04:41:06 2012 (4F4EEFD2)
fffff880`019b6000 fffff880`019f0000   fvevol    Thu Jan 24 04:11:24 2013 (5100A65C)
fffff880`01a8c000 fffff880`01ad5000   fwpkclnt  Thu Jan 03 04:06:48 2013 (50E4F5C8)
fffff800`03a02000 fffff800`03a4b000   hal       Sat Nov 20 14:00:25 2010 (4CE7C669)
fffff880`06b5e000 fffff880`06b82000   HDAudBus  Sat Nov 20 11:43:42 2010 (4CE7A65E)
fffff880`08762000 fffff880`0877b000   HIDCLASS  Wed Jul 03 06:05:05 2013 (51D3A2F1)
fffff880`0877b000 fffff880`08783080   HIDPARSE  Wed Jul 03 06:05:04 2013 (51D3A2F0)
fffff880`08754000 fffff880`08762000   hidusb    Sat Nov 20 11:43:49 2010 (4CE7A665)
fffff880`09ab8000 fffff880`09b81000   HTTP      Sat Nov 20 10:24:30 2010 (4CE793CE)
fffff880`01aed000 fffff880`01af6000   hwpolicy  Sat Nov 20 10:18:54 2010 (4CE7927E)
fffff880`0123c000 fffff880`01390000   iaStor    Tue Sep 14 03:23:32 2010 (4C8ECE94)
fffff880`057a2000 fffff880`057b8000   intelppm  Tue Jul 14 01:19:25 2009 (4A5BC0FD)
fffff880`010b3000 fffff880`010d4000   jraid     Tue Sep 07 04:37:00 2010 (4C85A54C)
fffff880`0f490000 fffff880`0f49f000   kbdclass  Tue Jul 14 01:19:50 2009 (4A5BC116)
fffff880`087cb000 fffff880`087d9000   kbdhid    Sat Nov 20 11:33:25 2010 (4CE7A3F5)
fffff800`00bb5000 fffff800`00bbf000   kdcom     Sat Feb 05 17:52:49 2011 (4D4D8061)
fffff880`10155000 fffff880`10198000   ks        Sat Nov 20 11:33:23 2010 (4CE7A3F3)
fffff880`01876000 fffff880`01891000   ksecdd    Sat Apr 12 03:08:30 2014 (5348920E)
fffff880`01a60000 fffff880`01a8c000   ksecpkg   Sat Apr 12 03:24:10 2014 (534895BA)
fffff880`06a18000 fffff880`06a1d200   ksthunk   Tue Jul 14 02:00:19 2009 (4A5BCA93)
fffff880`08fae000 fffff880`08fc3000   lltdio    Tue Jul 14 02:08:50 2009 (4A5BCC92)
fffff880`08f8b000 fffff880`08fae000   luafv     Tue Jul 14 01:26:13 2009 (4A5BC295)
fffff880`087d9000 fffff880`087dd300   lvbflt64  Fri Sep 21 21:01:00 2012 (505CB96C)
fffff880`08400000 fffff880`08454000   lvrs64    Fri Sep 21 21:02:17 2012 (505CB9B9)
fffff880`08a12000 fffff880`08e9b300   lvuvc64   Fri Sep 21 21:03:12 2012 (505CB9F0)
fffff880`08746000 fffff880`08754000   MBfilt64  Fri Jul 31 05:40:32 2009 (4A7267B0)
fffff880`00c59000 fffff880`00ca8000   mcupdate  Sat Nov 20 14:03:51 2010 (4CE7C737)
fffff880`08f7d000 fffff880`08f8b000   monitor   Tue Jul 14 01:38:52 2009 (4A5BC58C)
fffff880`0f49f000 fffff880`0f4ae000   mouclass  Tue Jul 14 01:19:50 2009 (4A5BC116)
fffff880`08784000 fffff880`08791000   mouhid    Tue Jul 14 02:00:20 2009 (4A5BCA94)
fffff880`01103000 fffff880`0111d000   mountmgr  Sat Nov 20 10:19:21 2010 (4CE79299)
fffff880`0158b000 fffff880`015cd000   MpFilter  Wed Jan 15 00:55:38 2014 (52D5CE7A)
fffff880`09b9f000 fffff880`09bb7000   mpsdrv    Tue Jul 14 02:08:25 2009 (4A5BCC79)
fffff880`09bb7000 fffff880`09be4000   mrxsmb    Wed Apr 27 04:40:38 2011 (4DB78226)
fffff880`09a00000 fffff880`09a4e000   mrxsmb10  Sat Jul 09 04:46:28 2011 (4E17C104)
fffff880`09a4e000 fffff880`09a72000   mrxsmb20  Wed Apr 27 04:39:37 2011 (4DB781E9)
fffff880`013c3000 fffff880`013ce000   msahci    Sat Nov 20 11:33:58 2010 (4CE7A416)
fffff880`0462b000 fffff880`04636000   Msfs      Tue Jul 14 01:19:47 2009 (4A5BC113)
fffff880`00e60000 fffff880`00e6a000   msisadrv  Tue Jul 14 01:19:26 2009 (4A5BC0FE)
fffff880`01818000 fffff880`01876000   msrpc     Sat Nov 20 10:21:56 2010 (4CE79334)
fffff880`04994000 fffff880`0499f000   mssmbios  Tue Jul 14 01:31:10 2009 (4A5BC3BE)
fffff880`019a4000 fffff880`019b6000   mup       Tue Jul 14 01:23:45 2009 (4A5BC201)
fffff880`0116d000 fffff880`011fa000   mv91xx    Mon Nov 22 08:00:45 2010 (4CEA151D)
fffff880`0dc98000 fffff880`0dc9e000   mv_process  Tue Feb 22 10:22:20 2011 (4D63804C)
fffff880`0142d000 fffff880`014bc000   mvs91xx   Tue Aug 09 05:05:23 2011 (4E40A3F3)
fffff880`013ce000 fffff880`013d6000   mvxxmm    Tue Aug 09 05:05:06 2011 (4E40A3E2)
fffff880`01afd000 fffff880`01bef000   ndis      Wed Aug 22 17:11:46 2012 (5034F6B2)
fffff880`101d2000 fffff880`101de000   ndistapi  Tue Jul 14 02:10:00 2009 (4A5BCCD8)
fffff880`0f400000 fffff880`0f42f000   ndiswan   Sat Nov 20 11:52:32 2010 (4CE7A870)
fffff880`06ccf000 fffff880`06ce4000   NDProxy   Sat Nov 20 11:52:20 2010 (4CE7A864)
fffff880`048f9000 fffff880`04908000   netbios   Tue Jul 14 02:09:26 2009 (4A5BCCB6)
fffff880`00c00000 fffff880`00c45000   netbt     Sat Nov 20 10:23:18 2010 (4CE79386)
fffff880`01a00000 fffff880`01a60000   NETIO     Tue Nov 26 11:21:01 2013 (5294760D)
fffff880`09a93000 fffff880`09ab4000   NisDrvWFP  Thu Mar 06 00:10:25 2014 (5317AEE1)
fffff880`04636000 fffff880`04647000   Npfs      Tue Jul 14 01:19:48 2009 (4A5BC114)
fffff880`04988000 fffff880`04994000   nsiproxy  Tue Jul 14 01:21:02 2009 (4A5BC15E)
fffff800`0341d000 fffff800`03a02000   nt        Tue Mar 04 09:38:19 2014 (531590FB)
fffff880`0162b000 fffff880`017d4000   Ntfs      Fri Jan 24 02:14:50 2014 (52E1BE8A)
fffff880`047a2000 fffff880`047ab000   Null      Tue Jul 14 01:19:37 2009 (4A5BC109)
fffff880`101de000 fffff880`101f7000   nusb3hub  Fri Nov 19 02:34:24 2010 (4CE5D420)
fffff880`057b8000 fffff880`057e9000   nusb3xhc  Fri Nov 19 02:34:25 2010 (4CE5D421)
fffff880`06ce4000 fffff880`06d18000   nvhda64v  Sun Jun 16 14:38:07 2013 (51BDB1AF)
fffff880`0f4d4000 fffff880`1012c000   nvlddmkm  Tue Mar 04 12:07:52 2014 (5315B408)
fffff880`048d3000 fffff880`048f9000   pacer     Sat Nov 20 11:52:18 2010 (4CE7A862)
fffff880`00eaa000 fffff880`00ebf000   partmgr   Sat Mar 17 06:06:09 2012 (4F641BC1)
fffff880`00e6a000 fffff880`00e9d000   pci       Sat Nov 20 10:19:11 2010 (4CE7928F)
fffff880`0109c000 fffff880`010a3000   pciide    Tue Jul 14 01:19:49 2009 (4A5BC115)
fffff880`010a3000 fffff880`010b3000   PCIIDEX   Tue Jul 14 01:19:48 2009 (4A5BC114)
fffff880`01903000 fffff880`01914000   pcw       Tue Jul 14 01:19:27 2009 (4A5BC0FF)
fffff880`0dca0000 fffff880`0dd46000   peauth    Tue Jul 14 03:01:19 2009 (4A5BD8DF)
fffff880`06d18000 fffff880`06d55000   portcls   Fri Oct 04 03:36:02 2013 (524E1B82)
fffff880`00ca8000 fffff880`00cbc000   PSHED     Tue Jul 14 03:32:23 2009 (4A5BE027)
fffff880`015cd000 fffff880`015d91a0   PxHlpa64  Mon Oct 17 16:29:34 2011 (4E9C3BCE)
fffff880`101ae000 fffff880`101d2000   rasl2tp   Sat Nov 20 11:52:34 2010 (4CE7A872)
fffff880`0f42f000 fffff880`0f44a000   raspppoe  Tue Jul 14 02:10:17 2009 (4A5BCCE9)
fffff880`0f44a000 fffff880`0f46b000   raspptp   Sat Nov 20 11:52:31 2010 (4CE7A86F)
fffff880`0f46b000 fffff880`0f485000   rassstp   Tue Jul 14 02:10:25 2009 (4A5BCCF1)
fffff880`04937000 fffff880`04988000   rdbss     Sat Nov 20 10:27:51 2010 (4CE79497)
fffff880`0f485000 fffff880`0f490000   rdpbus    Tue Jul 14 02:17:46 2009 (4A5BCEAA)
fffff880`04610000 fffff880`04619000   RDPCDD    Tue Jul 14 02:16:34 2009 (4A5BCE62)
fffff880`04619000 fffff880`04622000   rdpencdd  Tue Jul 14 02:16:34 2009 (4A5BCE62)
fffff880`04622000 fffff880`0462b000   rdprefmp  Tue Jul 14 02:16:35 2009 (4A5BCE63)
fffff880`0196a000 fffff880`019a4000   rdyboost  Sat Nov 20 10:43:10 2010 (4CE7982E)
fffff880`08fc3000 fffff880`08fdb000   rspndr    Tue Jul 14 02:08:50 2009 (4A5BCC92)
fffff880`084b5000 fffff880`08745e80   RTKVHD64  Tue Jan 04 12:48:55 2011 (4D230927)
fffff880`010d4000 fffff880`01103000   SCSIPORT  Sat Nov 20 11:34:01 2010 (4CE7A419)
fffff880`0dd46000 fffff880`0dd51000   secdrv    Wed Sep 13 15:18:38 2006 (4508052E)
fffff880`06a10000 fffff880`06a18000   serscan   Tue Jul 14 02:35:32 2009 (4A5BD2D4)
fffff880`01ae5000 fffff880`01aed000   spldr     Mon May 11 18:56:27 2009 (4A0858BB)
fffff880`0dc00000 fffff880`0dc98000   srv       Fri Apr 29 05:06:06 2011 (4DBA2B1E)
fffff880`0dd94000 fffff880`0ddfd000   srv2      Fri Apr 29 05:05:46 2011 (4DBA2B0A)
fffff880`0dd51000 fffff880`0dd82000   srvnet    Fri Apr 29 05:05:35 2011 (4DBA2AFF)
fffff880`014bc000 fffff880`01520000   storport  Tue Feb 04 02:36:50 2014 (52F04432)
fffff880`06a1e000 fffff880`06a1f480   swenum    Tue Jul 14 02:00:18 2009 (4A5BCA92)
fffff880`01c00000 fffff880`01dff000   tcpip     Sun Sep 08 03:11:52 2013 (522BCED8)
fffff880`0dd82000 fffff880`0dd94000   tcpipreg  Wed Oct 03 18:07:26 2012 (506C62BE)
fffff880`04669000 fffff880`04676000   TDI       Sat Nov 20 10:22:06 2010 (4CE7933E)
fffff880`04647000 fffff880`04669000   tdx       Sat Nov 20 10:21:54 2010 (4CE79332)
fffff880`04923000 fffff880`04937000   termdd    Sat Nov 20 12:03:40 2010 (4CE7AB0C)
fffff960`00420000 fffff960`0042a000   TSDDD     Tue Jul 14 02:16:34 2009 (4A5BCE62)
fffff880`0577c000 fffff880`057a2000   tunnel    Sat Nov 20 11:51:50 2010 (4CE7A846)
fffff880`0f4ae000 fffff880`0f4c0000   umbus     Sat Nov 20 11:44:37 2010 (4CE7A695)
fffff880`087de000 fffff880`087f8d00   usbaudio  Fri Jul 12 12:40:58 2013 (51DFDD3A)
fffff880`087ae000 fffff880`087cb000   usbccgp   Wed Nov 27 02:41:15 2013 (52954DBB)
fffff880`057e9000 fffff880`057eae80   USBD      Wed Nov 27 02:41:03 2013 (52954DAF)
fffff880`06be5000 fffff880`06bf7000   usbehci   Wed Nov 27 02:41:11 2013 (52954DB7)
fffff880`06c6a000 fffff880`06cc4000   usbhub    Wed Nov 27 02:41:36 2013 (52954DD0)
fffff880`06b8f000 fffff880`06be5000   USBPORT   Wed Nov 27 02:41:11 2013 (52954DB7)
fffff880`08ea8000 fffff880`08ec3000   USBSTOR   Fri Mar 11 05:37:16 2011 (4D79A6FC)
fffff880`06b82000 fffff880`06b8f000   usbuhci   Wed Nov 27 02:41:05 2013 (52954DB1)
fffff880`00e9d000 fffff880`00eaa000   vdrvroot  Tue Jul 14 02:01:31 2009 (4A5BCADB)
fffff880`047c2000 fffff880`047d0000   vga       Tue Jul 14 01:38:47 2009 (4A5BC587)
fffff880`047d0000 fffff880`047f5000   VIDEOPRT  Tue Jul 14 01:38:51 2009 (4A5BC58B)
fffff880`0111d000 fffff880`01159000   vmbus     Sat Nov 20 10:57:29 2010 (4CE79B89)
fffff880`01ad5000 fffff880`01ae5000   vmstorfl  Sat Nov 20 10:57:30 2010 (4CE79B8A)
fffff880`00ebf000 fffff880`00ed4000   volmgr    Sat Nov 20 10:19:28 2010 (4CE792A0)
fffff880`01040000 fffff880`0109c000   volmgrx   Sat Nov 20 10:20:43 2010 (4CE792EB)
fffff880`0191e000 fffff880`0196a000   volsnap   Sat Nov 20 10:20:08 2010 (4CE792C8)
fffff880`04908000 fffff880`04923000   wanarp    Sat Nov 20 11:52:36 2010 (4CE7A874)
fffff880`04600000 fffff880`04610000   watchdog  Tue Jul 14 01:37:35 2009 (4A5BC53F)
fffff880`00edd000 fffff880`00f9f000   Wdf01000  Sat Jun 22 05:13:05 2013 (51C51641)
fffff880`00f9f000 fffff880`00faf000   WDFLDR    Thu Jul 26 04:29:04 2012 (5010AB70)
fffff880`048ca000 fffff880`048d3000   wfplwf    Tue Jul 14 02:09:26 2009 (4A5BCCB6)
fffff960`000d0000 fffff960`003e7000   win32k    Fri Feb 07 02:23:07 2014 (52F4357B)
fffff880`01159000 fffff880`0116d000   winhv     Sat Nov 20 10:20:02 2010 (4CE792C2)
fffff880`06bf7000 fffff880`06c00000   wmiacpi   Tue Jul 14 01:31:02 2009 (4A5BC3B6)
fffff880`00e57000 fffff880`00e60000   WMILIB    Tue Jul 14 01:19:51 2009 (4A5BC117)
fffff880`048bf000 fffff880`048ca000   ws2ifsl   Tue Jul 14 02:10:33 2009 (4A5BCCF9)
fffff880`09a72000 fffff880`09a7d000   WSDPrint  Tue Jul 14 02:39:20 2009 (4A5BD3B8)
fffff880`1012c000 fffff880`10155000   Xeno7x64  Thu May 19 00:55:16 2011 (4DD44E54)

Unloaded modules:
fffff880`09be4000 fffff880`09bef000   WSDPrint.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0000B000
fffff880`06d77000 fffff880`06de8000   spsys.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  00071000
fffff880`09a72000 fffff880`09a93000   NisDrvWFP.sy
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  00021000
fffff880`019f0000 fffff880`019fe000   crashdmp.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0000E000
fffff880`01600000 fffff880`0160a000   dump_storpor
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0000A000
fffff880`046ce000 fffff880`0475d000   dump_mvs91xx
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0008F000
fffff880`04765000 fffff880`04778000   dump_dumpfve
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  00013000
```

### Further reading

- [Interpreting a Bug Check Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547224%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Bug Check Code Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh994433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Debugging Using WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh406283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

---

## Resolution

Installing a newer network card driver might help. While you're at it, consider updating the rest as well:

- **Ethernet**
  https://www.qca.qualcomm.com/resources/driverdownloads/
- **Audio**
  http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false
- **Video**
  http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us
- **Chipset**
  https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Software+Products&ProductLine=Chipset+Software&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+Chipset+Software+Installation+Utility

As for the BIOS, the current version is `F4a`. Despite being *beta*, Gigabyte claims it's stable:

> BETA describes a new version that is reliable yet may not include all the features of the final product. During this phase we are previewing new features and gathering customer input to insure our product provides the best experience possible.
>
> <sub>Source: [GIGABYTE - Motherboard - Socket 1366 - G1.Guerrilla (rev. 1.0)](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3776#bios)</sub>

Unless you updated the BIOS yourself, you should leave it as-is. Otherwise you might consider downgrading to version `F2`, which is the previous non-beta release.

Also, make sure you're using [latest Dropbox version](https://www.dropbox.com/release_notes).

Comment: I really like the detail in this answer.

Comment: I love this answer wish I could +100 you for it. You thought me how to fish. Thank you!

Comment: @feed_me_code You're welcome. Do let me know whether you solve(d) the problem. By the way, while you can't assign points directly, you can still place [bounties](http://superuser.com/help/bounty).

Answer (score 2):

According to the dump, the crash is caused by the Killer Xeno Gaming Adapter driver (Xeno7x64.sys) which is 3 years old, while you used Dropbox:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (d1)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If kernel debugger is available get stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00001000000102fd, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
Arg4: fffff88010143afd, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------

PROCESS_NAME:  Dropbox.exe

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
nt!KiPageFault
Xeno7x64
0x0
0x0
0x0
Xeno7x64
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
Xeno7x64
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
Xeno7x64


IMAGE_NAME:  Xeno7x64.sys

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xD1_Xeno7x64+17afd

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0xd1_xeno7x64+17afd


    Loaded symbol image file: Xeno7x64.sys
    Image path: Xeno7x64.sys
    Image name: Xeno7x64.sys
    Timestamp:        Thu May 19 00:55:16 2011
```

Look for a driver update.